# Why can't I input values?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, scanf

I can't input values without an error popping up, even though the code is correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf_s("%s", name);
    printf("Your Name is: %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I input a value to the name and press enter, an error message pops up and says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0FC13FD4 (msvcr120d.dll) in Project8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00D40000.
```

What is causing this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What's `scanf_s()`? Never heard of it.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Supposedly "safe" variant, created by Microsoft. In reality just an attempt of lock-in via API (since many so-called "safe" functions are basically just same old stuff with possibly reordered arguments). Funny in a way, to try to add supposedly safe functions into a language like C.

Comment: It's a must for Visual-studio 2013 to use instead of `scanf()`

Comment: We should come up with a new tag for the C-like language that Visual studio compiles. It certainly isn't C. Their C++ is reasonably standard, but their C doesn't resemble any other modern C that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (scanf_s("%99s", name, _countof(name)) == 1)
    printf("Your Name is: %s", name);
```

Two things

1. [`scanf_s()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w40768et.aspx) is a buffer overflow safe function, and it expects a length argument for `"%s"` specifier.
2. You should only proceed to `printf()` if you actually succeeded scannig the value, for which the check `(scanf(...) == 1)` is there.

   The `1` there, means one of the input parameters matched by the specifiers, since in this case there is only one of them, then it will mean a full match.

Also, I am almost sure that the `_countof()` macro, is defined as `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])` so this should also do it

```
if (scanf_s("%99s", name, sizeof(name)) == 1)
    printf("Your Name is: %s", name);
```

since in this case `sizeof(name[0]) == sizeof(char) == 1`.

Your code could work if you used the standard `scanf()` function, i.e.

```
if (scanf("%99s", name) == 1)
    printf("Your Name is: %s", name);
```

Comment: error C3861: '_countof': identifier not found.
But the code that I wrote should work. I've seen other people use it and it worked for them. It's working for me if I'm using a non-char.

Comment: @Simon `scanf_s` is not a standard function, so either don't use it, or try with the second suggested solution, i.e. use `sizeof`.

Comment: @Simon the code that you wrote will work assuming valid and correct input, and you shall never assume anything when it comes to input.

Comment: Alright, it works when using `sizeof`. I wanted to use `scanf()` but Visual-studio 2013 doesnt allow` scanf()` since it's not "safe" and thus recommending using `scanf_s()`

Comment: @Simon yes but `scanf_s` has different calling convention, BTW  did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: @Simon I added a link to `scanf_s()`'s documentation, please read it.

Comment: @Simon Yes there is a macro `_CRT_DISABLE_` something I don't remember.

Comment: I will. Thank you for your help. I found a way to remove the need to use `scanf_s` instead of `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [fgets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char name[100];
    printf("Enter your name: ");

    if (fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin) == NULL)
        return 1;

    printf("Your Name is: %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do so many programmers not check the return values of the functions they use? they return a value because it's useful, don't you think? Apart from that, this does not answer the question, it just suggest an alternate method, but it doesn't explain why the code failed.